# Are questions tagged [software] off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Some [such tagged, recent questions](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software?sort=newest&pageSize=50) remain open. [Mine](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/69485/26407) was closed.

Answer (score 2):

No, a question about software or how to use it is on topic. See the [tag description](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/software/info):

> For questions about musical computer programs used by musicians for
>   practice, performance, or composition. More popular software will have
>   a specific tag for it.

Software recommendations are off-topic here as expressed in our on-topic page expressed under the "Requesting external resources (questions should be specific and answerable on this site; external links are for references and supporting material)".

Besides being opinionated since different people prefer different things, it also tends to attract spam and self promotion. We can update the tag wiki to better reflect software recommendations are off-topic.

As a side note, any tag can produce an off-topic question the content itself determines if the question is on topic or not, not the tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

As Dom says, questions about how to use software are on-topic, so that's the most obvious 'allowable' use of the tag.

Generally it seems that we don't allow questions along the lines of 'what is some software that can do such and such a task'. So that would be an example of a question where the tag would seem relevant, but where the question itself wouldn't be allowed.

---

Having said that, although I personally wouldn't be keen to see subjective questions like "what's the best VST reverb plugin", **I *would* like to see questions like yours - "I want to do this job; is there any such tool that could achieve that task?"**.

Useful answers could be along the lines of "Yes, what you need is an 'XXXX' or a 'YYYY' - here are some examples of commonly-used ones". We wouldn't be asking for or giving subjective recommendations of quality, just conveying that something is available.

I do understand that such questions would date slightly, but that's also an issue with many other types of questions that we do allow.